# How to add multiple url in "CURLOPT_URL ="

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I am trying to get response from multiple url using API call and change color based on response. Problem is I want to get response from multiple url at the same time. But the program only can take the last url from the array.

I also tried using array for multiple url and looping but didn't work. Below is my code.

```
<?php

// An array of URLs to make requests to
$urls = array(
    'https://example.com/v1/objects/services?service=1', 
    'https://example.com/v1/objects/services?service=2'
);

// Create a new cURL multi handle
$mh = curl_multi_init();


$username = "root";
$password = "apipass";
$headers = array(
        'Accept: application/json',
        'X-HTTP-Method-Override: GET'
// Add each URL to the cURL multi handle
foreach ($urls as $i => $url) {
    $ch[$i] = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($ch[$i], array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
        CURLOPT_USERPWD => $username . ":" . $password,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0, 
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0
    ));
    curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $ch[$i]);
}

// Execute the cURL multi handle
do {
    $status = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
} while ($status === CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM || $active);

// Get the responses from each handle
foreach ($urls as $i => $url) {
    $response[$i] = curl_multi_getcontent($ch[$i]);
}

// Close the cURL multi handle and each individual handle
foreach ($urls as $i => $url) {
    curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $ch[$i]);
}
curl_multi_close($mh);

foreach ($response as $i => $response) {
   // check response and change color based on it
   if(strpos($response, "Unreachable") !== false) {
   $color[$i] = 'red';
      // success response
   } else {
   $color[$i] = 'green';
   }
} 
print $status;
print $color[$i];
?>
```

Comment: you could loop trough the requesturl array

Comment: Please do not ask multi-part questions.  if you are not able to do multi-url curling, then ask for help with that.  If you can do multi-url curling, then omit that step, show us the result of your curling and ask about how to generate the HTML.

Comment: @LucasdeRijke I have added an array of 2 url and created a loop as you suggested. There was no error but still it is taking the last url from the array. I am going to update my code in the question.